# Unity: Stop Character walk up hills (Angles between last Position & current Position?!)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm currently working on a small game in Unity, and i use c# for my code.

The game is a small role playing game, where you control a character like you do in games like world of warcraft or dragon age.

You run around on small maps, with hills around the map. Currently, you can walk up the hills at some places and i want to stop that.

so i thought i write a code where i get the last position of my character and the current position, than i get the angle between them and if the angle is to high, i would force the player to go back (or disable moving forward).

this is what i got for the code so far:

```
Vector3 lastPos; // last Position
Vector3 curPos; // current Position
float slopeAngle; // The angle between curPos and lastPos

void Start()
{
    curPos = transform.position;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    lastPos = curPos;
    curPos = transform.position;
    slopeAngle = Vector3.Angle(lastPos, curPos);
}
```

unfortunately, slopeAngle is mostly between 0 and 0.04. it doesn't matter if i run up a steep mountain or just a flat hill.

any ideas?! (if there is a better solution, than getting the angle between two points, i am very interested!! ) :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: id recommend just using the difference in height (z axis) of the current point and the next point, before applying the move. 

if you need to work it out based on angles, you can convert your forward movement and the desired angle into a height with trigonometry

Comment: i tried it with the y-positions now and the difference between last and current position, and so far it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a Raycast from your character to check if there's a slope high enough to halt your movement.

```
float maxSlopeAngle;
Transform raycastOrigin;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 direction = Quaternion.Euler(-MaxSlopeAngle, 0, 0) * transform.forward;
    if (Physics.Raycast(raycastOrigin.position, direction, out hit, 1f))
    {
         Debug.Log("Slope ahead!");
    }   
}
```

Obviously, you'd want to figure out the right maxDistance for the raycast so you won't stop too soon.

Also, you can use the following script to help you figure out the right angle:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SlopeAngleHelper : MonoBehaviour {

    public float MaxSlopeAngle;
    public Transform RayOrigin;

    void Update () 
    {
        Vector3 direction = Quaternion.Euler(-MaxSlopeAngle, 0, 0) * transform.forward;
        Debug.DrawRay(RayOrigin.position, transform.forward, Color.black, 0.01f, false);
        Debug.DrawRay(RayOrigin.position, direction, Color.red, 0.01f, false);
    }
}
```

Just put it on your character object and it will "visualize" the raycast in scene view.

Comment: i tried your answer but it shows me "slope ahead!" even if i'm walking on a flat ground. i increased the angle to 45 degrees and it's still detecting the flat ground?!

Comment: Try adding the following line inside the if-clause `Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject);`. This will show you which object the Raycast collided with. If it collides with the ground, move the RayOrigin transform slightly higher. If it collides with the player, make sure that the RayOrigin transform is INSIDE the player collider.